# AWS AppSync Amplify Relationship with Transformer v2 - Can't Retrieve related type data

Tags: amazon-web-services, relationship, aws-amplify

So I am currently playing with AWS AppSync and Amplify, and all is good except, with the new Transformer V2, I am struggling to get things to work.

Here's my schema:

```
type Post
  @model
  @auth(
    rules: [
      { allow: owner, ownerField: "username" }
      { allow: public, operations: [read] }
    ]
  ) {
  id: ID!
  title: String!
  content: String!
  username: String
    @index(name: "postsByUsername", queryField: "postsByUsername")
  coverImage: String
  comments: [Comment] @hasMany
 
}


type Comment
  @model
  @auth(
    rules: [
      { allow: owner, ownerField: "createdBy" }
      { allow: public, operations: [read] }
    ]
  ) {
  id: ID!
  message: String
  
}
```

I can create a post and a comment. However, whenever I query a list of posts, I never get comments.

Here's an example of a query:

```
query MyQuery {
  listPosts {
    items {
      comments {
        items {
          id
          message
          createdAt
        }
      }
      content
      title
      username
    }
  }
}
```

and here's the corresponding result I get:

`````
{
  "data": {
    "listPosts": {
      "items": [
        {
          "comments": {
            "items": []
          },
          "content": "Testing stuff",
          "title": "Today is the day",
          "username": "bawp"
        },
        {
          "comments": {
            "items": []
          },
          "content": "### hello\n````\n function call()\n```",
          "title": "next item of the day",
          "username": "paulod"
        },
        {
          "comments": {
            "items": []
          },
          "content": "Hello Word",
          "title": "santo dia",
          "username": "paulod"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
`````

Notice how the

```
     "comments": {
            "items": []
          },
```

It is always empty!

Even though, when I query the Comments table, I get at least one comment added.

```
query MyQuery {
  listComments {
    items {
      id
      message
      createdBy
    }
  }
}
```

Result:

````
{
  "data": {
    "listComments": {
      "items": [
        {
          "id": "ddddf58b-df1c-498c-97b4-6d61361b4b9e",
          "message": "Thjis is may coment here\n\n```\nCode could go here also!\n```",
          "createdBy": "paulod"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
````

I am not sure what I am missing here.  Remember I am using new directives (Transformer v2) as opposed to the old relationship directives like

```
@connection
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, this is a response to my question for anyone who might run into some of these issues.

Firstly,

The schema!
Since I am adding some relationships between the tables, the directives must be added correctly. Here are the changes I made to my schema:

```
type Post
  @model
  @auth(
    rules: [
      { allow: owner, ownerField: "username" }
      { allow: public, operations: [read] }
    ]
  ) {
  id: ID!
  title: String!
  content: String!
  username: String
    @index(name: "postsByUsername", queryField: "postsByUsername")
  coverImage: String
  comments: [Comment] @hasMany(indexName: "byPost", fields: ["id"]) #check out: https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/graphql/data-modeling/#has-many-relationship
}

#Comment
#queries: null - removes any authorization rules for queries, allowing anyone to query for comments
#ownerField:createdBy - sets the createdBy field as the currently signed in user
type Comment
  @model
  @auth(
    rules: [
      { allow: owner, ownerField: "createdBy" }
      { allow: public, operations: [read] }
    ]
  ) {
  id: ID!
  message: String
  post: Post @belongsTo(fields: ["postID"])
  postID: ID @index(name: "byPost")
 
}
```

Next, because appsync autogenerates the `queries.js` file on each push, I had to edit this file manually (which is not really a final solution). In particular, the listPosts query:

```
export const listPosts = /* GraphQL */ `
  query ListPosts(
    $filter: ModelPostFilterInput
    $limit: Int
    $nextToken: String
  ) {
    listPosts(filter: $filter, limit: $limit, nextToken: $nextToken) {
      items {
        id
        title
        content
        username
        coverImage
        comments {
          items {
            id
            message
            postID
            createdAt
            updatedAt
            createdBy
          }
        }
        createdAt
        updatedAt
      }
      nextToken
    }
  }
`;
```

You see, when this file is autogenerated, it would have "nextToken" instead of having fields that I wanted to query. In other words, the `comments` field would have `{ nextToken  }`

So, the query would look like this:

```
export const listPosts = /* GraphQL */ `
  query ListPosts(
    $filter: ModelPostFilterInput
    $limit: Int
    $nextToken: String
  ) {
    listPosts(filter: $filter, limit: $limit, nextToken: $nextToken) {
      items {
        id
        title
        content
        username
        coverImage
        comments {
          nextToken # --> this is what was autogenerated, which was giving me issues!!!
        }
        createdAt
        updatedAt
      }
      nextToken
    }
  }
`;
```

Once I changed `nextToke` with what I showed you earlier in the post, it all worked perfectly.

Now, I know that changing this file manually doesn't seem right. However, I am not in the process of figuring out a better way to do this.

But for now, that's what I was able to come up with.

I hope this helps somebody running into similar issues.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I have applied the schema just like you did in the answer, but also made the `postId` field important.

I think that has helped get the nested comments.

[image]

```
type Post
  @model
  @auth(
    rules: [
      { allow: owner, ownerField: "username" }
      { allow: public, operations: [read] }
      { allow: private, operations: [read] }
    ]
  ) {
  id: ID!
  title: String!
  content: String!
  username: String
    @index(name: "postsByUsername", queryField: "postsByUsername")
  coverImage: String
  comments: [Comment] @hasMany(indexName: "byPost", fields: ["id"]) #check out: https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/graphql/data-modeling/#has-many-relationship
}

#Comment
#queries: null - removes any authorization rules for queries, allowing anyone to query for comments
#ownerField:createdBy - sets the createdBy field as the currently signed in user
type Comment
  @model
  @auth(
    rules: [
      { allow: owner, ownerField: "createdBy" }
      { allow: public, operations: [read] }
      { allow: private, operations: [read] }
    ]
  ) {
  id: ID!
  message: String
  post: Post @belongsTo(fields: ["postID"])
  postID: ID! @index(name: "byPost")
}
```